# Function inverses

Tags: inverse-function

From the definition of a inverse standpoint ($f^{-1}(f(x))=f(f^{-1}(x))=x$), why does interchanging variables ($x$ and $y$) work to find the inverse? It seems logical to me but I cannot come up with a coherent argument as to why.

Comment: While I think I know where this is going, I want to clarify: are you seeking justification for finding the inverse of a given function, which is taught at the elementary level as usually just "swap the variables and solve for your new $y$" or "just solve for $x$ in terms of $y$"? (I recall seeing both when I was in grade school.)

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I'm seeking justification for the first one: "swap the variables and solve for your new y". That's how I was taught it in school, but now that I'm doing linear transformations in linear algebra and looking more closely at functions in group/set theory, I realize that I never really understood why what they taught me in school was valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we find the inverse in this way, we are not really ‘interchanging variables’. We’re just rearranging to find the input in terms of the output (when usually we have the output defined explicitly in terms of the input), and then relabelling to make it clearer. It just happens that we usually use $y$ to refer to the output of a function and $x$ to refer to the input.

An inverse function $f^{-1}$ is just a function that ‘undoes’ the operation of $f$, so when we find the input in terms of the output we are simply finding what operations are required to turn the output of $f$ back into the input, which we often call $x$.

As a simple example, suppose $y = 3x + 2$. Then $\frac{y - 2}{3} = x$.

We didn’t interchange any variables and we have found the inverse. However, if we want to write it in the ‘standard’ $y = f(x)$ way, we can relabel to find $y = \frac{x-2}{3}$.

This is all quite loose because we are not really manipulating functions—just expressions. Really, we are taking $f(x)$ in terms of $x$ and finding $x$ in terms of $f(x)$. But you can see hopefully more intuitively why this technique works when we have relatively simple functions defined like this.

$$\rule{4cm}{0.4pt}$$

Since I feel like I have tried to fully address your concern about ‘interchanging variables’, let me try to give some extra reasoning about why we can ‘rearrange’ an equation like we did above to find the inverse.

Any function that we can write like we did above can be expressed as a composition of intermediate functions. Consider what happens to the input $x$ in our example above: first it gets multiplied by $3$ and then it gets added to $2$.

As I said, the inverse is just an ‘undoing’ function. It takes us back from the output to the input again. When we rearrange an equation, what we are doing is repeatedly applying functions to both sides.

When we find the inverse using our rearranging technique...

$$y = 3x + 2$$

$$\text{(apply $f(\lambda) = \lambda - 2$ to both sides)}$$

$$y - 2 = 3x$$

$$\text{(apply $f(\lambda) = \frac{1}{3}\lambda$ to both sides)}$$

$$\frac{y - 2}{3} = x$$

...we are just applying the inverse operations of the function, in the reverse order, which of course will undo the operation of the function.

This is also why functions that are not one-to-one do not have inverse functions—we can’t undo their operation as we did here because we don’t know which input lead to a specific output.

Comment: The intuition makes sense, but is it possible to come up with a rigorous proof of this?

Comment: Whilst I appreciate that you want to be very sure that this technique always works, there is not really any need for a rigorous proof beyond saying that the inverse of $f(x)$ is defined by $f^{-1}(f(x)) = x$ (this is a rigorous definition) and that if we denote $f(x)$ by $y$ then we have $f^{-1}(y) = x$ which is the same thing as $y = f^{-1}(x)$ by simply relabelling as I described above. In fact, I would argue that what I wrote is essentially a rigorous proof—just one that is in words rather than purely symbols.

Comment: I think intuition is perhaps more important for you here, since it is a relatively trivial truth.

Comment: I added some extra information that I hope helps you.

Answer (score 1):

From your definition, suppose that $(x,y)$ is on that function, we have

$x=f^{-1}(f(x))=f^{-1}(y)$.

Now like you said, if we change $x$ and $y$, we obtain $y=f^{-1}(x)$, which is the inverse.